# Watching a YouTube video disconnects my Internet connection

Tags: networking, windows-10, google-chrome, youtube, windows-10-v1709

Using Windows 10 (v1709) and Chrome (64.0.3282.167), when I watch a YouTube video, my Internet connection works for approximately the first minute, then drops out.

In more detail: I can watch a video for a short period of time (typically anywhere from 30 seconds to 2 minutes), then YouTube's "stats for nerds" shows the connection speed dropping from 30-40MB/s to around 100 kB/s, and DNS lookups start failing. Chrome gives me the dinosaur for any other website I try to connect to from that point on, even if it's not YouTube. Doing things online without visiting a YT video has no issues and the connection will stay up for as long as I want.

My connection is set up such that my PC is connected via Ethernet cable to a first-level access point on my desk, which is connected via Ethernet to a cable modem/router downstairs. Both cables test good for continuity. Rebooting either my first-level access point or my computer fixes the issue, but it's a pain.

Using Ubuntu instead on the same machine (dual-boot), I have no issues.

I've had a look around to see if there are any known fixes for this, but it seems most people having this issue had it in 2013 and the problem was AVG antivirus trying to be more-than-antivirus. I do not have AVG, nor is it 2013.

I am confuse. What can I do?

Comment: So what security software do you use?  Any commercial AV can break SSL, Google only uses SSL, if you suspect an SSL problem (which where your thought about AVG should be pointing towards) what AV solution your using is important.  If you use a VPN do you encounter the same problem?

Comment: @Ramhound No VPN. Defender for AV. I don't think it's an SSL issue, though, no indications that it could be.

Comment: I ask if you use a VPN, do you have the same problem, I already know you are not using a VPN.

Comment: @Ramhound Hard to tell, but so far no issues on a VPN.

Comment: What do you mean, "hard to tell", you indicate the problem surfaces within 2 minutes.  If it does not happen within 2 minutes, then, the problem does not exhibit itself while connected to a VPN.  What part of the world are you in?  If you are part of the developing world, it's possible, your ISP is being ultra-aggressive in its bandwidth filtering. As to the reason it works on Linux, trivial, to identify what OS you are using based on headers.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm in the UK. And no, it's hard to tell because it's an intermittent problem - it happens most of the time, but it's working right now. I'll keep trying. I doubt my ISP is deliberately filtering _only_ YouTube on _only_ Windows, though - that just wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @Ramhound Got a repro. Problem still occurs on VPN.

Comment: If you lower the quality of the video does it work?  YouTube only supports higher resolution rates on Windows

Comment: @Ramhound I _am_ on Windows, so it should support high-res. Changing it doesn't help, anyway.

Comment: I have the same issue. Windows 10, using powerline adapters, internet connection intermittently fails while viewing Youtube videos - sometimes it resolves itself but quickest solution seems to be disabling the connection and re-enabling (have disabled the "Allow computer to turn off device to save power" option in device manager but it seems as though it's still doing this or something similar).

Comment: I posted a solution that allows you to restore your connection within seconds, but unfortunately a moderator deleted it for unknown reasons.

Comment: That'd be because I flagged it as "not an answer", @Devabc. I'm not (well, I wasn't - this is long since fixed) looking for a solution to reconnect the internet, but to stop it disconnecting in the first place.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I understand that is isn't a full solution, but it's better than nothing. I have the same problem, I couldn't find a full solution, so I'm using my script when it happens. In my case it happens less often than that you have, for these people, my solution can still be helpful. I posted it, because I care. It surprises and disappoints me that you caused my effort to help people like you, to be completely removed. You can downvote it, but you flag it like it's spam.....

Comment: @Devabc Answers are there for _answers_. Not partial answers, not comments, not try-this. If you have something that's helpful but not an answer, put it in a comment. This system is how SE has become such a valuable resource.

Comment: @ArtOfCode SE states that flagging should be used for inappropriate content,such as spam,abusive posts,and for posts that are not an answer.My question is an answer, maybe not the answer you liked, and not a 100% solution answer, as are *many* answers at SE, but it is an answer. If you don't like an answer, than you should use the downvote feature. SE says that you should downvote when: "you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.". I believe that you have incorrectly flagged my post,against the guidelines of SE.

Comment: @Devabc Like I said, answers are for answers, _not_ partial answers. The NAA flag is more than appropriate for partial answers, and there's clearly at lease one other moderator who agrees with that.

Comment: I often connect to my faster deksktop using windows remote desktop, when I open a youtube video on that one, I get disconnected from remote desktop. And I have a permanent ping to my desktop (it stops responding on LAN when it streams from Youtube). Just like YouTube would use 100% of network. But my LAN is 1Gbps, WAN/Youtube is 300Mbps max.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I know this is an old question, but you mention 'this is long since fixed'. Do you remember what the solution to the problem was or did it just resolve itself?